# XDebug doesn't stop on breakpoints set on Yii controllers' actions

Tags: netbeans, yii, controller, action, xdebug

I code in Yii framewor, using Netbeans 8.0.1 and also Eclipse. My local developement environment is build on XAMPP. I can see, that breakpoints set anywhere within Wordpress code works just fine. But, when I try to set a breakpoint on any Yii's controller or action, XDebug won't stop at that point. It only work on `index.php` of my project.

However, `xdebug_break()` work for controllers, but not actions.

My `php.ini` settings for `XDebug` are:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.remote_server = 127.0.0.1
```

I'm trying to deal with this problem for about a week and still didn't come with any solution.

Comment: Try removing everything besides `remote_enable` and `idekey`, since most of the values you're using are the default for XDebug, add `xdebug.remote_log=C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.log` and please post the contents of your log file so we have a better understanding of what's happening.